# Two NiMH AA batteries powering servo circuit

Tags: power, pcb-design, esp32, servo, nimh

My project has an ESP32 C3 and 9g servo. It has to be mobile, thus battery powered. Due to space constraints, I can’t use 4 AA batteries even though that would be ideal. I would like to use two NiMH instead and convert the nominal 2.4 V to 5 V for the servo and 3.3 V for the MCU. I can’t use LiPo for safety reasons.

The good news is it is only going to be run for around 5-10 seconds at a time, a couple times a day, and can be recharged regularly.

I’m wondering if there’s any pitfalls using only the two AAs, and what the best way would be to get the 3.3 and 5 V out of it, like two separate boost circuits?

Comment: If you maintain ESP at low power consumption (most of time in sleep, turn device on occasionally, etc) you can just use 5v boost+3v3 linear regulator.

Answer (score 0):

> I’m wondering if there’s any pitfalls using only the two AAs, and

In a small servo, its DC motor may need a current of about 500 mA to 1 A, to overcome inertia, reaction forces, or Coulomb friction.
A higher output voltage implies the use of a step up converter, resulting in even higher input current drains. Assuming 100% efficiency for a first crude estimation, to provide Vout = 5.0V and Iout = 1A where Vin ~= 2.0 V, Iin = 2.5A as peak supply current.
For 2x NiMH being new and well charged, their internal resistance is low and the nominal voltage of 1.2V probably will not drop below 2.0V.
So, a step up converter from 2.0 V < Vin < 2.4~2.6 V, to Vout = 5.0 V  seems to be perfectly feasible, specially if the mechanical load on the servo is not high, resulting in lower drain currents.
Just as a reference, there are several step-up modules based on the IC [MT3608](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Breadboarding/BB-PWR-3608/resources/MT3608.pdf) showing it can operate from 2.0 to 24 V, managing enough switching current for your application. The switching quiescent current also seems low enough (1.0 ~ 2.2 mA) for your source as 2x AA NiMH (C ~= 1800 mAh) assume that quiescent current fine - as you said, recharging can be done regularly.

> what the best way would be to get the 3.3 and 5 V out of it, like two separate boost circuits?

For this, I would use just one step-up converter to Vout = 5.0 V and for it I would use a low dropout linear regulator to provide the 3.3V for the ESP32, which would be much cleaner output (of noise) than using another step-up converter.

My thought would initially check if the [HT7333](https://www.angeladvance.com/HT73xx.pdf), with Dropout Vdrop ~= 90 mV @ 40 mA and a low quiescent current Iq < 10 uA and tentatively installing some electrolytic + ML Ceramic capacitors to mitigate the high-current drain bursts from the ESP32’S WI-FI; but check carefully this solution to avoid oscillations due to high capacitive loads. This might be adequate for your application, but it may not be a jelly-bean regulator promptly available.

If a much higher quiescent current as 5~11 mA would be temporarily acceptable to you while providing higher “burst current” for the ESP32, you could try other options as the [AMS1117-33](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf) or even a [L78L33](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l78l.pdf) (with its input voltage increased to 5.3 V due to higher Vdrop) could work, although not the best choices for battery operation due to minimum voltage dropout or minimum quiescent current figures.